# Trouble with getting strings into JSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, arraylist

My servlet recieves/loads multiple parameters from/for an article (`price`, `id`, `count`, `name`).

While they are saved in the session for other purposes I want to display them in a Shopping cart.

So my idea was to get all values into a `jso`n like this

```
{"id":1, "prductName":"article1"}
```

but my `json` always ends up empty.

I had two approaches:

```
String prname = request.getParameter("name");
String anz = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("Anzahl"));
String prid = request.getParameter("id");
String price = request.getParameter("price");
```

These are my parameters:

First try:

```
class ToJson{

        String prname1 = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("prname"));
        String anz1 = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("Anzahl"));
        String prid1 = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("id"));
        String price1 = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("price"));
    }

    ToJson obj = new ToJson();
    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    String jsn1 = jsonb.toJson(obj);
```

Ends up with: `{}`

Second try:

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    ar.add(prname);
    ar.add(price);
    ar.add(prid);
    ar.add(anz);
ToJson obj = new ToJson();
    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    String jsn = jsonb.toJson(ar);
```

Ends up with: `["P1neu","25","1","145"]`

It isn't in a format I wanted and I also don't know how to access the seperate values here, I tried `jsn[1]` but it didnt work.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: is this really "javascript"? you have tagged your question as javascript, did you mean Java instead?

Comment: Building json by hand can be tedious task.
Try to leverage a library that can do this work for you - like Jackson.

Here's a starting point: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Comment: @hovanessyan thanks. I added it and I got a string with String obj1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj); But any idea why my servlet shows a blank page when I use it?

Comment: @r314 you need to write the obj1 string to the response body you are returning from your servlet and set the content type to "application/json". Use the response object to set the ContentType and use the same response object to get a PrinterWriter. Write the obj1 in the PrinterWriter - don't forget to flush it and that should work.

Comment: @hovanessyan  `out.append(obj1);  out.flush();         out.close();` Would this work? My response type is `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, `why JSON object is printing empty`:

> You are missing `getters & setters` in the `ToJSON` class for JSON Builder/Parser to access the properties/fields, and that's why its printing as empty object.

To your second question, `how do I access JSON properties`:

 JSON representation is a natively a string representation, and you can't read part of string as `jsn[1]`.

> For reading JSON object properties, you convert it into POJO using available any of preferred open source parser libraries like Jacksons, Gson etc. And then access POJO properties using standard java getter/setters.